# Suggestion needed on SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 4 fields like:

```
Country, Year, Area,Value
USA , 2010, SQL, 78
USA, 2011, C++, 66
UK, 2012, C, 99
```

Now in this table

- 3 Areas are there (SQl, C++, C) and 3 different years are there.
- So USA has missed 1 year and 1 area, UK has missed 2 years and 2 areas.
- I want to insert those missing values in to ‘0’(zero).

The result should additionally contain:

```
USA, 2012, C , 0
UK, 2010, SQL, 0
UK, 2012, C++, 0
```

Just like loop through by country and missing areas (as per the entries in table), years (as per the entries in table) and need to fill “0”s. In sql functions/query/triggers/anything.

I tried like this:

```
SELECT countryID, COUNT ("chart_data"."countryID") AS count 
FROM tablename GROUP BY "countryID", "yearID"...
```

Is this possible?

Comment: You have tagged several SQL environments in your question. Which one does the question relate to?

Comment: specially needed for postgresql!!

Comment: I'm not an expert but the "query" must run in all these rdms ? N the question is all about an update statement !! I guess -)

Comment: Are you currently having the rows with value = 0 ? If not, you should use an INSERT statement instead of a SELECT one.

Comment: yes insert only i have to use, but before that i need to search whether country has other areas and other values... if not insert 0

Comment: Vijayakumar, if you are solving this, you also expert only.. by my poit of view :P

Comment: Have you looked at Postgresql's `generate_series` function? You could use that to UNION to your result set to fill in any gaps. I don't have time to post a proper answer however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the answer for Postgresql or MySQL, but it should work on other DBMS as well:

```
INSERT INTO tbl (Country, Year, Area, Value)
SELECT Countries.Country, Years.Year, Areas.Area, 0 As Value
FROM
  (SELECT DISTINCT Country FROM tbl) Countries CROSS JOIN
  (SELECT DISTINCT Year FROM tbl) Years CROSS JOIN
  (SELECT DISTINCT Area FROM tbl) Areas
  LEFT JOIN tbl ON tbl.Country=Countries.Country
                   AND tbl.Year=Years.Year
                   AND tbl.Area=Areas.Area
WHERE
  tbl.Value IS NULL -- if it can't be null, otherwise choose any other field
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5c0cc/1).

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot. it looks great this one is the correct solution. I dont have reputaion over 15... else i can give more votes :)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer.
But the scenario has been changed little bit.
1. The USA, UK, 2013, 2014, C++ and java are in specific separate table(i.e, countrytable, yeartable and subjectable) and used in this table as secondary id. - But we should get this same result.
2. One more change is we should not alter the table, just need to do get the result(i.e, select instead of insert)

   
Please suggest me on this as you did before.